# ¿Cuál puede ser un buen equivalente del "fellow" inglés?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, prefijos

Con frecuencia en inglés lees cosas como:

> What's the best way to inform a pedestrian or ***fellow cyclist*** that I'm about to pass them? ([pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4139/1674))
>
> Why are ***fellow users*** removing thank-you's from my questions? ([pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/1983854))

Se ve la tendencia: dado un colectivo X, en inglés dicen *fellow X* para referirse al grupo de personas

Si el colectivo X consiste en personas que tienen el mismo nombre, diríamos [*tocayos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZwMRuMo). Si consiste en otras personas de la misma ciudad o nación, entonces es [*conciudadanos*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A9EZAps). Y, en general, muchos usan el *co* como en *colaborador*:

<sub>No puedo evitar compartir la última cosa que me ha deslumbrado de Google: la etimología visual.</sub>

[image]

Ahora supongamos que quiero hablar de mis [compañeros moderadores](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). ¿Cómo podría nombrarlos? ¿Comoderadores? ¿Co-moderadores? ¿Hay alguna partícula siempre aceptable?

Comment: No sé si habrá una palabra que valga para todo en español, me da la impresión que en inglés ocurre más eso, en español según el contexto usamos palabras distintas. Yo creo que compañeros podría valer en la mayoría de los casos

Comment: @fedorqui De acuerdo con blonfu en cuanto a la versatilidad de "compañeros". Me parece que en inglés predomina el prefijo "co-" (*coworkers*) mientras que en español usamos más "con-" (o "com-", cuando sigue una "p" o "b"): *connacionales, conjueces, compatriotas*. Y sí, diría "co-moderadores" (o "compañeros moderadores").

Comment: @Gustavson ¡gracias! Entonces, ¿mejor _co-moderadores_ que _comoderadores_ todo junto?

Comment: @fedorqui Me gusta más con guion que sin guion. Creo que tiene que ver con el hecho de que "comoderador" no es una palabra habitual y, en esos casos, es mejor mantener una cierta independencia entre el prefijo y la palabra principal. Compara con "copropietario". Iba a arriesgar que las formas "con-" y "com-" parecen más comunes cuando subyace la idea de compañero, o sea, alguien que hace la misma actividad, y que "co-" parece más común cuando se comparte una tarea o un atributo. Pero tenemos el caso de "condómino", quien comparte el dominio de una cosa. Me parece que la elección es por sonido.

Comment: @Gustavson comparto la apetencia, hace más fácil la comprensión. Dicho lo cual, yo creo que tus comentarios dan para una muy buena respuesta :)

Answer (score 2):

¿colega ciclista? ¿colega moderador?

Dixit RAE:

> colega
>
> Del lat. collēga.
>
> 1. m. y f. Compañero en un colegio, iglesia, corporación o ejercicio.
> 2. m. y f. coloq. Amigo, compañero.